# NSDate comparison off by one day

Tags: swift, datepicker, nsdate

I'm trying to compare days between two dates - (current date and a user picked date) - and store the difference in a variable `var daysleft = 0`

However, the code I'm using makes `daysleft` always display 1 day too little. Basic terms : The current date and tomorrows date results in the same value (`0`)

Comparison code;

```
var daysleft = 0

let DayDifference = userCalendar.components(
        dayCalendarUnit,
        fromDate: Date,
        toDate: dateView.date,
        options: [])

    daysleft = DayDifference.day
```

> EXTRA CODE;

Here is some extra code if you need to take  a look at the user-picked date code;

```
datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date
    sender.inputView = datePickerView
    datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: Selector("datePickerValueChanged:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)


func datePickerValueChanged(sender:UIDatePicker) {
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.NoStyle
    DateTextField.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)
    dateMakerFormatter.calendar = userCalendar
    dateMakerFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"
}
```

> EDIT

Here are the dates I'm using for example;

Current date as;

```
let Date = NSDate()
```

User-picked date;

```
var datePickerView:UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
let dayCalendarUnit: NSCalendarUnit = [.Day]
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date
    sender.inputView = datePickerView
    datePickerView.addTarget(self, action:   Selector("datePickerValueChanged:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

func datePickerValueChanged(sender:UIDatePicker) {
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle
dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.NoStyle
DateTextField.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)
dateMakerFormatter.calendar = userCalendar
dateMakerFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"
```

}

Comparison;

```
dayCalendarUnit,
    fromDate: Date,
    toDate: datePickerView.date,
    options: [])

daysleft = DayDifference.day
```

Comment: It'll be easier for us to help you if you include what dates you were using for calculation and what the expect result is

Comment: @CodeDifferent Look at the last part, everything is there I think. All dates are off by one day - and current date (27 march) vs tomorrow (28 march) -  displays 0 as day difference.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there is not a full day difference (24+hours) between the two dates.

You need to get the day for each with `component:fromDate:` and subtract the days. You may need to handle months and years.

or

Set the time to 0 for each prior to the calculating the day difference with `components:fromDate:toDate:options:`.

Answer (score 0):

Because your `today` has time so the difference to the user's picked date is less than 24 hours away.

You need to trim the time components off:

```
let userCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()

// Only get the Year, Month, Day of `now`
let components = userCalendar.components([.Year, .Month, .Day], fromDate: NSDate())
let today = userCalendar.dateFromComponents(components)!

// Assume the user picked Mar 28, 2016
let userPickedDate = userCalendar.dateWithEra(1, year: 2016, month: 3, day: 28, hour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0, nanosecond: 0)!

let dayDifference = userCalendar.components([.Day], fromDate: today, toDate: userPickedDate, options: [])

print(today)
print(userPickedDate)
print(dayDifference.day)
```

Comment: How can I make the userPickedDate change with what the user chooses? Seems to me that it is now stuck with 28th of October 2016?!

Comment: As swift says: "Cannot convert value of type (UIDatePicker) to value (NSDate)